# Adding value to each row

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe and for each row (column value) I would like to add +5. Meaning that I would leave the original numbers and add 5 to each.

Dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd 
info= {"Num":[12,14,13,12,14,13,15], "NAME":['John','Camili','Rheana','Joseph','Amanti','Alexa','Siri']}
 
data = pd.DataFrame(info)
print("Original Data frame:\n")
print(data)
```

Output:

```
Original Data frame:
  
   Num   NAME
0   12    John
1   14  Camili
2   13  Rheana
3   12  Joseph
4   14  Amanti
5   13   Alexa
6   15    Siri
```

Desired output:

```
   Num   NAME
0   17    John
1   19  Camili
2   18  Rheana
3   17  Joseph
4   19  Amanti
5   18   Alexa
6   20    Siri
```

Attempt to solve:

```
for i,e in enumerate(data['Num']):
    data.at[i,'Num']= +5
```

output:

```
data
Out[391]: 
   Num    NAME
0    5    John
1    5  Camili
2    5  Rheana
3    5  Joseph
4    5  Amanti
5    5   Alexa
6    5    Siri
```

Would appreciate an example with a for loop

Comment: `data['Num'] += 5` ? without `for`-loop.

Comment: You say you want to add 6, but the desired output and the code attempt both suggest you actually want to add 5. The problem here is a simple typo: `=+` is not the same as `+=`. But most importantly, you should **ask an actual question**. Please read [ask]. In this case, you should have explained what went wrong when you tried your code, i.e. that all the values become `5` instead of the desired sum.

Comment: Also, you don't need to loop. You can add the value directly to the column; the operator is overloaded for you. That sort of thing is why you use Pandas in the first place.

Comment: @Karl Knechtel that's not even the point whether it's 5 or 6. the question is how would you update each original value with +5 or +6 or +100 doesn't matter.     df.at[i,'Order_Demand'] += 1000 doesn't work either which I tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd 
info= {"Num":[12,14,13,12,14,13,15], "NAME":['John','Camili','Rheana','Joseph','Amanti','Alexa','Siri']}
 
data = pd.DataFrame(info)
```

Answer:

```
for index in range(len(data)):
    data['Num'].iloc[index] += 5
```

Output:

```
data
Out[617]: 
   Num    NAME
0   17    John
1   19  Camili
2   18  Rheana
3   17  Joseph
4   19  Amanti
5   18   Alexa
6   20    Siri
```

Answer (score 1):

You need simple

```
data['Num'] += 5
```

without `for`-loop